# How can I escape $ sign with a string (Ex $log) in Helm yaml file

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

First of all, I know that if it is a single `$` sign that I can escape with `$$` sign. My scenario is something like `$log`. I want that to print as it is.

Things I have tried so far:

- If I give `$log`, it will set an empty string
- If I give `$$log`, then it will set only `$`
- Tried with setting as a `env` in the same values.yaml file but same results as above

How can I resolve this issue?

### Update:

My values file is like below:

```
fluent-bit:
    env:
      - name: LOGSERVICE_FLB_RULE_DEFAULT_KEY
        value: $log
    image:
    .
    .
    .
        [FILTER]
            Name          rewrite_tag
            Match         kube.*
            Rule          $kubernetes['container_image'] ^.+solr:.+$ format.logging.solr false
            Rule          $kubernetes['container_image'] ^.+zookeeper:.+$ format.logging.zookeeper false
            Rule          ${LOGSERVICE_FLB_RULE_DEFAULT_KEY} ^.*$ format.logging false
            Emitter_Name  re_emitted_with_tag
```

What my expectation is:

```
    Rule          $kubernetes['container_image'] ^.+solr:.+$ format.logging.solr false
    Rule          $kubernetes['container_image'] ^.+zookeeper:.+$ format.logging.zookeeper false
    Rule          $log ^.*$ format.logging false
```

But what I'm getting at is:

```
    Rule          ['container_image'] ^.+solr:.+$ format.logging.solr false
    Rule          ['container_image'] ^.+zookeeper:.+$ format.logging.zookeeper false
    Rule           ^.*$ format.logging false
```

Comment: Which `helm` version is used? I will try to find a solution

Comment: helm version is `Version:"v3.5.4"`

Comment: Can you give an example template where you're trying to use this?  Helm on its own doesn't have any particular global rule around escaping `$`.

Comment: @AnujAroshA Do you run `helm template .` to see it or it happens during creation? I have `helm 3.7.0`, pulled `fluent/fluent-bit` chart, entered the same values as you provided in the question and when I run `helm template .` it shows exactly as your expectations. Can you try to update `helm` itself?

Comment: @moonkotte yes, you are correct. Once I update the Helm version it got solved. Please update your comment as an answer then I can accept. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the answer out of comments.

---

After attempt to reproduce the issue, it worked as expected result.

The only visible difference is `helm` version which was used: in question it's `3.5.4` while I used `3.7.0`.

Updating to last stable version resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

To escape the dollar sign in Helm values.yaml you can write the following string:

```
{{ printf "$" }}$$authenticated
```

That will produce an output:

```
$authenticated
```